# Junit @Before not working properly

Tags: java, junit

```
@Before
public void setup(){
    Ground ground = new Ground(100, 100);
}

@Test
public void getDimX(){
    String msg = "For a newly created Ground(100, 100), ground.getDimensionX()      should return 100";
    assertEquals(100, ground.getDimensionX());
}
```

The above code returns a NullPointerException. If I move the `Ground ground = new Ground(4, 4);` into the `getDimX()` method, the test runs just fine. I have a number of tests that will use the same ground, so I would prefer not to make a new one with each test case. Also, if I get rid of the `@Begin` block entirely and just leave the ground instantiation, it also works fine. What then is the point of the `@Before?`

Comment: This question ends up being about language syntax (not understanding local variables), not `@Before` as such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

created a private field in your test class outside your test setup, i.e.

```
public class MyTest{
    private Ground ground;
    ...
}
```

Then instantiate ground in your `before()`

```
@Before
public void before(){ground = new Ground(100,100);}
```

Comment: This didnt do the trick for me ! I am facing the exact same issue !

Answer (score 16):

I had faced this issue when instead of org.junit.Test I had imported
 org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

Comment: Someone give this person a trophy please !
You saved me from hours of mindless scanning through imports between two different test classes. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

Agreeing with @ANU JOHN,
the following imports didn't match up:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
```

Changing the second to org.junit.Test; fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your test class doesn't extend `TestCase`:

```java
public class TestHelloWorld {
    private Hello h;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        h = new Hello();
        ...
```